# Angularjs Routing not working with other config options

Tags: angularjs, routes, ngroute

I'm new to `angular` trying to implement routing in my angularjs app. My app does the followings

1. user can login via facebook
2. then he/she can select a link to navigate

Following is my main `angularjs` file (with route and facebook connect, facebook connect is working :)), My problem is , routing doesnt work..

```
#app.js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['facebook', 'ngRoute'])

    .config([
        'FacebookProvider',
        function(FacebookProvider) {
            var myAppId = '<FB app ID>';
            FacebookProvider.init(myAppId);

        }

    ],
     function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            // route for the home page
            .when('/add', {
                templateUrl : '../pages/add_form.html',
                controller  : 'addCtrl'
            })

            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            });
      }  
    )
```

and when I add a debug pointer to line `.when('/add', {`control flow is not coming to that line at all.

Following is my href

`<li><a href="#add">Add & Edit Recipes</a></li>`

I'm following [this tutorial](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating) for routing , any help would be greatly appreciated

** UPDATE **

my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="gt-ie8 gt-ie9 not-ie" data-ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    //stuff
    <body class="theme-default no-main-menu main-navbar-fixed" data-ng-controller="MainController">

      <script>var init = [];</script>
      <div id="main-wrapper">
        // some html
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Home&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="navbar-icon fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-ng-show="logged">
        <li><a href="#/add">Add & Edit Recipes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Unpublished</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Published</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Recipe</a></li>
    </ul>

        <div id="content-wrapper">
          <div ng-view>
            <%= yield %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main-menu-bg"></div>
      </div> 

    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Try <a href="#/add">. Also, look into your templateUrl. When you run the page in debug mode, go into the Network settings, and when you try to navigate to /add, see if you get a 404 or a 200 status code when it requests '../pages/add_form.html'

Comment: @Onosa, thanks for the quick reply, unfortunately nothing happens when I changed to "#/add" and I can see nothing in Networksettings as well

Comment: Are you using `html5mode`? Unless whats the `hashprefix`?

Comment: When you click on "Add & Edit Recipes", another request is not sent? Hmm... Could we see more of the html, then? I'm wondering if it's not part of your angular domain. Like, is it inside an ng-app or controller tag?

Comment: @Onosa, thanks again , I updated my HTML (only the parts needed to avoid the mess) :)

Comment: I've been looking at this over and over and I just can't figure anything out. Did you see that the tutorial you linked had a working code demo at http://embed.plnkr.co/dd8Nk9PDFotCQu4yrnDg/preview

Comment: @Onosa, yeah I checked that, but I guess the problem is there is something wrong when I try to combine both `route` and `facebook` connect modules in `app.js`. Thanks for your time again.